# Como adicionar dois eventos no datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Preciso fazer com que os eventos do datepicker sejam adicionados dependendo de onde for clicado. Por exemplo: preciso filtrar alguns dados pelo dia e posso filtrar os mesmos dados também por mês.

Mas com o meu código, só está funcionando o evento do mês, pois ele é acionado quando eu clico em algum dia do mês seguinte

```
$('#calendario').datepicker({
      format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
      language: "pt-BR",
      startDate: '+0d'
  }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
      let data = e.format(0,"yyyy-mm-dd");
      location.href  = '/cursos?date=' + data;
  })
  .on('changeMonth',function(e) {
      let obj_mes = e.date;
      let mes = obj_mes.toString().split(' ');
      let mes_ano =  $(".datepicker-switch").html();
      let ano = mes_ano.split(' ');

      location.href  = '/cursos?mes=' + mes[1] + "&ano=" + ano[1];
  });
```

Comment: Esses eventos só vão capturar se o usuário clicar no datepicker, caso ele digite no input não funcionará, sugiro tratar tudo no "change"

Comment: Mas no "change" ele perde o evento quando troca de ano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode capturar todas as alterações com o `onChange` e dentro dele comparar a mudança de valor nas datas para saber qual lógica aplicar.

Segue abaixo exemplo com comentários explicativos:

```js
$('#calendario').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    language: "pt-BR",
    startDate: '+0d'
}).on("change", function(e){  

  //Pego o valor selecionado anteriormente
  var oldValue = $(this).attr("data-value");
  
  //Se não for a primeira alteração devo comparar as datas:
  if(oldValue != ""){
    date1 = novaData(oldValue);
    date2 = novaData($(this).val());
    
    if(date1.getFullYear() != date2.getFullYear()){
      console.log("Mudou o ano"); 
      //Coloque sua lógica se mudou ano
    }else if(date1.getMonth()+1 != date2.getMonth()+1){
      console.log("Mudou o mês"); 
      //Coloque sua lógica se mudou o mês
    }else if(date1.getDate() != date2.getDate()){
      console.log("Mudou o dia do mês"); 
      //Coloque sua lógica se mudou o dia do mês
    }
  }
  
  //Salvo a nova data selecionada no atributo data-value
  $(this).attr("data-value", $(this).val());
});

//Evita problemas com timezone ao definir a data
function novaData(dataString){
  var partes = dataString.split('-');
  var data = new Date(partes[0], partes[1] - 1, partes[2]); 
  return data;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<!-- crio atributo data-value para armazenar penultima data escolhida -->
<input type="text" name="calendario" id="calendario" data-value="" />
```

Comment: É isso mesmo!!!